# Android AppCompact material design tint for status bar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-statusbar

I want to achieve the status bar described in the Material Design guidelines where the color should be 20% darker than the Toolbar.
I have set the following styles:

**Styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

**Style.xml (v21)**

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

But I get complete different layouts than expected.

**Emulator 4.4**

[image]

**Emulator 5.0.1**

[image]

**Sony Z3 5.0.1**

[image]

Is there a proper technique to make the Status Bar 20% trasparent (even by code), send the Toolbar and Drawer on back of the Status bar and avoid the usage of *FitSystemWindows* on Toolbar which stretch all over my screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Note that it does only work from Android 4.4 (KitKat), there is no way to tint the system bar on Android versions before 4.4.